# mercurial error on fresh checkout: untracked files in working directory differ from files in requested revision

Tags: mercurial

I did a clone of a mercurial repo with "hg clone url" then when I try to switch to another branch using "hg checkout branch_name" I'm getting the error "abort: untracked files in working directory differ from files in requested revision"

So what's going on here? There are no local changes. I just did a fresh clone and immediately tried to switch branches.

Comment: How did you do your clone? Did you used the `--stream` option? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Do you recognize the untracked files? `hg st` will list them, for instance

Comment: 1st time using mercurial, but I'm pretty sure all the untracked files are supposed to be tracked. But I deleted everything hg st output and was then able to checkout the branch.

Comment: I faced this issue once on Windows due to VS renaming my files to lower case and I was using an extension that automagically committed with the renamed. The solution was to track down the changeset and to strip it or histedit.